# Bootstrap 3.1 How to use mixin make-grid-columns()?

Tags: grid, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I used to use Bootstrap 3.0, and compiled my css from the bootstrap less files + some of my own less.

In this some of my classes adopts some bootstrap styles like this:

```
.myClass{
    .col-md-3;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    [etc, etc]
}
```

It worked out great in Bootstrap 3.0, since all col-md-X classes are defined as less variables. But in Bootstrap 3.1 this seems to be somehow replaced with a mixin function called make-grid-columns().

Does anybody know how to utilize this mixin, and how to port the construction above into Bootstrap 3.1? :-/

Answer (score 60, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less), you can use the `.make-md-column(3);` mixin, for example:

```
.myClass{
    .make-md-column(3); /* Replaces .col-md-3; */
    border: 1px solid #000;
    [etc, etc]
}
```

Answer (score 16):

This is the grid written in classic bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">Meow</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">Meow</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">Meow</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">Meow</div>
</div>
```

And this is self compiled:

```
.productgrid {

  .make-row();
  .clearfix;

  .product {

    .make-xs-column(12);
    .make-sm-column(6);
    .make-md-column(4);
    .make-lg-column(2);
  }
}
```

The result markup will look like this:

```
<div class="productgrid">
  <div class="product">Meow</div>
  <div class="product">Meow</div>
  <div class="product">Meow</div>
  <div class="product">Meow</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @mcolegro it clears all floats. but probably you can skip this because the make-row already do this